# How to set up custom functionality on a Wordpress site?

Tags: javascript, wordpress

Let's say I have a one-page Javascript-heavy web application.

But for the rest of the site, I want the easy of creating content pages with Wordpress.

Should I:

- Have the web application in the root, install Wordpress in a sub-folder and apply the same theme to both (ugh)?
- Somehow write the application as a plugin for Wordpress? If so, where do I start?
- Other?

### Edit

The app in question is simple in that there is a form on the page, with custom divs underneath it. The jQuery/Javascript script does the hard work by manipulating those divs to add content, based on what was submitted in the form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally I would create a file in the theme called application.php for example and write the following in it

```
    <?php
    /*
    Template Name: ApplicationPage
    */
    ?>
//PASTE THE PHP CODE OF YOUR PAGE.PHP STARTING FROM GET_HEADER();
//REPLACE GET_CONTENT() WITH YOUR JAVASCRIPT
```

Followed by a copy and paste of your page.php in the theme folder. In this way you create a new template only just to be used for your application.Where there is the the_content() replace it with your heavy javascript.

Once saved then create a new page and on the right side you should have a dropdown with the templates... here select ApplicationPage and press Save.

Now when you visit this page this should have the custom code you included in application.php

For a better overview : http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-themes/how-to-create-a-custom-page-in-wordpress/

Answer (score 0):

You can always install Wordpress in a subdirectory, but that won't get you far if you wish to integrate wordpress functionality into the rest of your site.

This really depends on the amount of effort you wish to invest into this process. Ideally, you could create a wordpress theme (and possibly a plugin, depending on what you're trying to do). Wordpress has decent docs on how to create themes and plugins. Take a look at the URL below for more information.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development

**Note:** I don't know what your existing web app does or how complex it would be to integrate into wordpress or vice-versa, so this is just a general answer.

**Edit:**

Based on your edit above, since your app is mostly contained in a single page with a lot of JS, I would probably opt to create a wordpress theme(+plugin). The plugin would cover your app's server side logic and the theme would contain your custom app (as a page) in addition to the common wordpress functionality.

Comment: Thanks. I added a slightly better description in my edit above.